# Wiener process - calculating the variance

Tags: normal-distribution, variance

I have a simple question for the wiener process.

In the book: options, futures and other derivatives by Hull there is a chapter about wiener processes.

There it states, that a wiener process has 2 properties:

1) When ϵ is a standard normal distribution ϕ(0 , 1) (mean zero and variance of 1)
and a small change in z during a small period of time is given by:

```
                                ∆z=ϵ√∆t
```

2) The values of Δz for two different short time intervals are independent.

My question then is:

**How do I get the variance for ∆z?**

I know the answer from the book is ∆t, but how is this calculated?

My problem is, that I really don't know how to calculate it, when there is a distribution function in the equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have the following result:

If $a$ is a constant, and $X$ is a random variable, then 
$$E\{aX\}=aE\{X\}$$ and   $$Var\{aX\}=a^{2}Var\{X\}.$$

---

Given that $\Delta z = \varepsilon \sqrt{\Delta t}$,  where $\varepsilon \sim N(0,1)$.

That is, $E\{\varepsilon\}=0$ and $Var\{\varepsilon\}=1$.

The distribution of $\Delta z$ also becomes normal with

$$E\{\Delta z\} = \sqrt{\Delta t}\cdot E\{\varepsilon\}=\sqrt{\Delta t}\cdot 0 = 0,$$ and

$$Var\{\Delta z\} = (\sqrt{\Delta t})^{2} Var\{ \varepsilon\}=\Delta t\cdot 1 = \Delta t$$.